# Скрыть кнопку добавит в избранное, плагин Wp-recall

Tags: wordpress

Я использую на своем сайте (Wordpress 4.1) плагин Wp_Recall и его дополнение Bookmarks, чтобы давать возможность пользователям добавлять посты в закладки, а потом просматривать их из личного кабинета (запилен на вышеназванном плагине).
Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы кнопка "добавить в избранное"
скрывалась на тех постах и страницах, которые пользователь уже добавил  в избранное.
Плагин (по утверждению самих разработчиков) такого не предусматривает.

Comment: Вам стоит дополнить вопрос, поскольку тут два варианта, или через куки или пользователь должен быть зарегистрирован. Так что код в студию или ссылки.

Comment: Спасибо, что быстро откликнулись. Ниже вариант решения от самого разработчика плагина, этот вариант работает.

Answer (score 3):

```
    add_action('wp','remove_bookmarks_button');
function remove_bookmarks_button(){
    global $post,$user_ID,$wpdb;
    if(is_singular()){
        $bkms = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".RCL_PREF."bookmarks WHERE post_id='%d' AND user_id='%d'",$post->ID,$user_ID));
        if($bkms) remove_filter('the_content','add_button_bmk_in_content',20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей.

Comment: Вариант, предложенный Вами, помог.